# django "x time ago" outside templates

Tags: django

I know that in templates you can use [naturaltime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime)

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ video.pub_date|naturaltime }}
```

But is there anyway to implement this in python code?

```
class SomeObject(models.Model):
  req_tm = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
      return SomeFunction(self.req_tm)
```

Does `SomeFunction` exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template filters are just functions. All you need to do is import the function from the module and you can use it in any Python code.

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime

class SomeObject(models.Model):
    req_tm = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return naturaltime(self.req_tm)
```

Comment: I assume that you mean `from django.contrib.humanize import naturaltime` but that doesn't exist.

Comment: `>>dir(django.contrib.humanize)
>>['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'apps', 'default_app_config']`

Comment: Sorry for the bad import path. I've corrected it. Reference: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py

Comment: But `humanize` doesn't have `templatetags`. `'module' object has no attribute 'templatetags'`

Comment: Works for me: `>>> from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime`

Comment: What version of Python and Django are you using?

Comment: You forgot to add humanize to the end of the your import :) That fixed it.

Comment: Derp. Sorry - it's very late on my side of the world.

Comment: I think you need to approve my edit to get published. SO doesn't this noob :|

Comment: The edit was rejected since I had made the same change.